# aura: iteration issues

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have this lightning component that successfully gets knowledge articles from KnowledgeArticleVersion and I have verified the correct data coming through dev console logs... However, I am having some trouble using aura atrributes. I am unable to get the component to actually render the data. I am guessing my issue has something to do with trying to return list data to SObject[] type, thus not allowing {!article.Id} etc to render any data in the component.

Any ideas?

.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="GetHBArticles">
    <aura:attribute name="articles" type="SObject[]"/>

    <ui:button label="Get Articles" press="{!c.getArts}"/>
    <aura:iteration var="articles" items="{!v.articles}">
        <p>{!articles.Id} : {!articles.Title} : {!articles.ArticleType}</p>
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

lightning controller

```
({
    getArts: function(cmp){
        var action = cmp.get("c.getArticlesList");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.articles", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

apex controller

```
public with sharing class GetHBArticles {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<List<SObject>> getArticlesList(){
        List<List<SObject>> articles = [FIND :searchVar RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion
                                                     (Id, Title, ArticleType WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND ArticleType IN ('Troubleshooting__kav', 'How_To__kav', 'FAQ__kav'))
                                                     WITH DATA CATEGORY Topics__c AT 'DataCategoryName];
        return articles;
    }



}
```

As always any help from this awesome group is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you're missing a helper class, but that's just with taking a cursory look. I'm confident that someone who writes more Lightning will come along and give you more direction.

Comment: I was unaware that the helper class is necessary to load the data. Thanks for the tip I will read into it more. This is the example I was referencing https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_records.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@AllenMann you could fix this in two ways:

1.Return `List<KnowledgeArticleVersion>` instead of `List<List<SObject>>` to do so you have to change `getArticlesList` method as below:

```
 @AuraEnabled
 public static List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> getArticlesList(){
    List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = [FIND :searchVar RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion
                                                 (Id, Title, ArticleType WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND ArticleType IN ('Troubleshooting__kav', 'How_To__kav', 'FAQ__kav'))
                                                 WITH DATA CATEGORY Topics__c AT 'DataCategoryName'][0];
    return articles;
 }
```

2.Use the first element(i.e index = 0) of the response which is an array containing an array of `KnowledgeArticleVersion` data in `lightning controller`

```
  var result = response.getReturnValue();
  if(result.length && result[0].length)
     cmp.set("v.articles",result[0]);
```

Comment: Wasn't able to get the first one working right. Would the aura attribute type need to be changed also? I tried to change it to KnowledgeArticleVersion[] with no luck. Trying your second suggestion now. Thanks for your time @Praveen.

Comment: @AllenMann aura:attribute's type is fine no need to change it.

Comment: @AllenMann Happy to help :-)

Comment: In the lightning controller you did if{result.length && result[0].length before sending the data to the component. Is the length variable assumed to have been created and given an integer used for limiting results?

Comment: Since `List<T>` or even nested list `(List<List<T>>)` ( i.e your case) in Apex(server side)  is treated as **Javascript Array** in Lightning component(client side) which has length property by default and whose values is the size of the **JS Array**.
The `IF` condition checks if the response has result,if it had data in it ,then the result.length would have value greater than `0` inturn the `If` block would have executed(in your setting the aura:attribute value)
`T` - Any Apex Supported Data Type